# Why React renders an empty text node in the React DOM tree?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React 16.0.0. 
When there is an inline IF with an empty string passed in, React adds an empty text node in the React DOM tree. It appears in React Developer Tools but nothing is added in the browser DOM tree. For example:

```js
const title = '';
....
{title && <div>Test</div>}
```

However if we use the boolean coercion it doesn't push the empty text node in the React DOM:

```js
const title = '';
....
{!!title && <div>Test</div>}
```

Is there a big difference in using/avoiding the coercion from the performance perspective if in both cases nothing is added in the browser DOM?

Comment: Internals probably only check boolean as opposed to falsy to prevent problems like not printing `0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `React` has nothing to do with it. It's just how `JavaScript` works:

```
'' && 'sometext'
> ''

!!'' && 'sometext'
> false
```

An empty string will resolve in JSX as itself (`""`) and the value `false` is ignored.

I don't think there is a "performance" penalty for using either one. Just use the one you think is more readable.